# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't work with thunderbolt 3 docking station and multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, docking

I have ubuntu 20.04 installed on my Dell XPS 13 9350. I'm running kernel 5.8.0-50-generic. I recently got a Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 dock gen 2 docking station. Connecting the dock station to the laptop works fine apart from the monitors -- two MSI Optrix AG32CQ monitors connected via Display ports.

The BIOS is the latest -- BIOS rev 1.13.0.

After connecting the dock station the USB disks, speaker, webcam etc. works fine. Not the monitors, however. In the display menu, under hardware settings, it displays the presence of two additional monitors. But,both monitors are dark, one of them indicated it is turned on, while the other one is off. Without any changes, pressing "Apply", results in three warnings being displayed in individual pop-up windows:

1. **Failed to apply configuration: %s**

   Time out was reached.
2. **The selected configuration for displays could not be applied**

   Could not set the configuration for CRTC 64
3. **Could not switch the monitor configuration**

   Could not set configuration for CRTC 65

After this I have to disconnect from the dock and reboot to get back to normal. Could someone advice on how to proceed, please?

On a side note: the same hardware/software combination work fine with a DisplayLink driver (version5.4) and a Dell 6000 docking station, apart from the fact that here I cannot close the lid on the laptop without corrupting the screens on the two remaining monitors.

Comment: Have you recently updated BIOS on the laptop and drivers on the docking station? I believe it's recommended. Why the old 5.4 kernel? Because it's LTS, unlike the newer ones used in Ubuntu 20.04? Nevertheless, 5.8 is available for 20.04.2. Also maybe the bottleneck is not your laptop's old hardware (older (but not ancient) hardware tends to be better at compatibility), rather the docking station? Oooops, excuse me? _Thinkpad_ dock with _Dell_ laptop? Then, it's like gambling, isn't it. Either works or not. Even Dell doesn't recommend all _their_ docking stations with all their laptops, AFAIK.

Comment: No idea! I can't even tell how can you be on a kernel so behind. For me, it progresses on its own with the regular software updates... (Maybe you had to do something explicit to keep at that version?) But I'm sure this site already has the info somewhere: use the search...

Comment: "the OS complains about that it can not configure and issues with some timeout" — Copy-paste the exact text of the error message into your question. The exact text of error messages are always very useful / important, because if you put them in a web search, you often find some enlightening information among the results.